# How to set whenever gem crontab fail mail notification in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, cron-task, whenever

i have one crontab in the shedule.rb like below. i want to capture the crontab below rake task crontab error log in a email instead of error.log.

**schedule.rb:**

env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :output, {:error => 'log/error.log', :standard => 'log/cron.log'}
every 1.day, :at => '8:00 am' do
    rake "att:upload_data"
end

How to handle/capture the error logs in a email?

Answer (score 0):

You could [use a class](https://github.com/javan/whenever#example-schedulerb-file) instead of a rake task and do error handling there:

```
every 1.day, :at => '8:00 am' do
  runner 'DomainName.upload_data'
end
```

If you need to reuse the rake task you can execute it from your class:

```
require 'rake'

class DomainName
  def self.upload_data
    Rake::Task['att:upload_data'].execute
  rescue SomeError => e
    MyMailer.rake_error(e)
  end
end
```

Also, if you just want to get notified of errors by email you could consider using a [3rd party service](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20error%20tracking).